# Can't retrieve value with dynamic entry add

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've a problem.
I want to dynamically add empty entries when I click on a button. It's ok for that, I've my empty entry and the user can write something.
But I don't know how to retrieve the value of each entry when I click on an another to validate.

My xaml code :

```
  <StackLayout x:Name="EntriesStackLayout" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

            <Grid RowSpacing="0" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout x:Name="ChoiceEntries" Grid.Row="0">
                    <Entry
                        Margin="0,30,0,0"
                        Placeholder="Choix 1"
                        ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        x:Name="FirstChoice_Entry"
                        />
                    <Button
                     Text="add"
                     Clicked="AddNewEmptyEntry_Clicked"
            />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
```

My C# code :

```
        void AddNewEmptyEntry_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddEntry(EntriesStackLayout, "Attribut " + entryCount.ToString());
    }

    private void AddEntry(StackLayout entriesStackLayout, string v)
    {
        if (entryCount <= 5 )
        {
            Entry entry = new Entry()
            {
                Placeholder = $"Choice {entryCount++}",
                ClearButtonVisibility = ClearButtonVisibility.WhileEditing,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
            };

            entriesStackLayout.Children.Add(entry);
        }
        else
            alertNumberChoice_label.IsVisible = true;
    }


     private void RetrieveValueFromEntry_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // I want get value from each entry here.
    }
```

So thanks to my C# code, I can add empty entry each time I click on the "add button". But I can't get the value. Maybe it's not the best way to do this I don't know.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Looks you are not using MVVM. If you use MVVM. This can be easy. In ViewModel you should have observable collection list that will be bound to XAML layout. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts.  Whenever you click on the button add new model in the list that will automatically grow entry in your view. Validation can be done in the observable collection it self. While binding entry make it as twoway. So, that edited values in the entry will be reflected in the model of the list.

Comment: MVVM sample code link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: you need to maintain a reference to the new entry you created so you can retrieve the value.  This can be as simple as having a `List<Entry>` that you add it to, or you can create some more complex data structure.  Or as @Ranjit suggests you can bind the `Entry` to a VM property and get the values that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign event for each entry.

```
        entry.Completed += RetrieveValueFromEntry_Clicked;
```

Add this line in your code where you create entry and you can use value of each entry in RetrieveValueFromEntry_Clicked method

```
private void AddEntry(StackLayout entriesStackLayout, string v)
    {
        if (entryCount <= 5 )
        {
            Entry entry = new Entry()
            {
                Placeholder = $"Choice {entryCount++}",
                ClearButtonVisibility = ClearButtonVisibility.WhileEditing,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
            };
            entry.Completed += RetrieveValueFromEntry_Clicked;
            entriesStackLayout.Children.Add(entry);
        }
        else
            alertNumberChoice_label.IsVisible = true;
    }


     private void RetrieveValueFromEntry_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var oldVal = e.OldTextValue;
        var newVal = e.NewTextValue;
    }
```

You can use **TextChanged** event instead **Completed**. It depends on your requirement.

Hope this will help you. Let me know if any help

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through its child controls and if the type of it's child view is `Entry`, them you can get the text of it.
please refer to  the following code:

```
    private void RetrieveValueFromEntry_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // I want get value from each entry here.
        int childnum = EntriesStackLayout.Children.Count;

        List<string> strList = new List<string>();

        foreach (View view in EntriesStackLayout.Children) {
            if (view is Entry) {
                strList.Add(((Entry)view).Text);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("child value = " + ((Entry)view).Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If my reply is useful for you, could you please mark it as answered so that it will help others who have similar thread？ Thanks in advance.